# Help with some special characters (░█)

Tags: fonts, unicode, input-encodings

I am trying to get these two characters to render properly (░█). So far, I tried using \verb, utf8 encoding, utf8x encoding, using lualatex with a few different fonts following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25251) method. Each time, it either did not compile, or rendered the characters as blank spaces.

Here is a basic version of the code :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{float}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\large Text}
\setlength{\headheight}{18pt}
\begin{document}
    <text>
    \subsection{ <░█░█░░█░█░█░> \textemdash{} Keygen Church}
    <more text>
\end{document
```

Update : I've botched together a "working" solution by saving the text as an image and doing this:

```
\subsection{\includegraphics{Images/text.png} \textemdash{} Keygen Church}
```

Solution: see [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/679754/293140). I used `ablatross ░` to get a list of compatible fonts and used one of them instead of Cascadia.

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete document, all the way from begin to end. Then we will know what packages you use, your settings, and so forth. First question: Are you using a font that actually has the requested characters?

Comment: I used courier, which should have the correct characters ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courier_(typeface)#IBM_Courier) is a table, though it's for the IBM variant but I reckon the base table should have them too)

Comment: that table you link to is not a Unicode font so it may have some characters that look like  `░` but it has not got a character `░` ie character U+2591 you would have to do a custom maapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Firefox reported it used a font Cascadia Mono to show your question, so I told lualatex to use the same. You may have different fonts, but you can use whichever font your browser finds for these characters.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\blockfam{Cascadia Mono}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\large Text}
\setlength{\headheight}{18pt}
\begin{document}
    <text>
    \subsection{{\blockfam <░█░█░░█░█░█░>} \textemdash{} Keygen Church}
    <more text>
\end{document}
```